# XPath Count function always return 0.0

Tags: java, xml, xpath, domdocument

I'm using below xml to get the count of tag 'c'.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xyz xmlns=".....">
<a>
  <b>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:2 Y:0</c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>X:1 Y:0</c>
    <c>X:2 Y:0</c>
  </b>
</a>
</xyz>
```

Below is my java code :

```
xpath = factory.newXPath();
xpr = xpath.compile("count(//xyz/a/b/c)");
System.out.println(xpr.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.NUMBER));
```

But the above code always returns 0.0

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: For starters, your XPath is not taking the namespace into account.

Comment: But I just tried my use-case here .. http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output it gave me output as 5.0

Comment: @peeppeep How are you creating the input source? The XPath doesn't seem to be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count elements with the local name of `xyz`, the expression should be as follows:

```
XPathExpression xpr = xpath.compile("count(//*[local-name()='xyz']/*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b']/*[local-name()='c'])");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/A0DH9J)

Comment: This still returns 0.0

Comment: @peeppeep It turns out that the same trick needs to be applied to the other three levels (see the edit and the demo).

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete the namespace attribute value. It is important because that is the actual namespace.

A `xmlns="urn:somevalue"`defines a default namespace for elements. A `<xyz xmlns="urn:somevalue"/>` or a `<ns1:xyz xmlns:ns1="urn:somevalue"/>` can be both read as node name `{urn:somevalue}:xyz`.

XPath 1.0 does not have a default namespace. You always have to use an prefix for nodes in a namespace.

So if you define the prefix `ns1` in a namespace resolver for your XPath the expression would be:

```
count(//ns1:xyz/ns1:a/ns1:b/ns1:c)
```